Error running ansible-test on community.aws collection
I'm trying to run integration tests on the Ansible collection community.aws.
I installed Ansible, forked and cloned the repo, and created the cloud-config-aws.ini file. However, when I run
ansible-test integration elb_network_lb --docker -v
I get this error
ERROR! couldn't resolve module/action 'amazon.aws.aws_az_info'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/root/ansible_collections/community/aws/tests/output/.tmp/integration/elb_network_lb-zkpngdxv-ÅÑŚÌβŁÈ/tests/integration/targets/setup_ec2_facts/tasks/main.yml': line 23, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Get available AZs
      ^ here

When I run
ansible localhost  -m amazon.aws.aws_az_info
it works so I know permissions are correct.
How can I solve this issue?
